# How can I debug this function with v_operation and v_message?

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sync_from_xml()
RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
myxml    xml;
datafile text := 'Documenti/ABBATE_EMANUELE_Lvl1F2Va_20160418-1759.xml';
BEGIN

myxml := pg_read_file(datafile, 0, 100000000); 

CREATE TABLE tmp AS
SELECT (xpath('//some_id/text()', x))[1]::text AS id
FROM   unnest(xpath('/xml/path/to/datum', myxml)) x;
END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;

SELECT * from tmp;
```

This function should allow to transform a XML into postgres table. This function doesn't give an error but not create the table. How can I use v_operation and/or v_message to find possible errors?

Comment: how do you understand it does not create a a table?..

Comment: Yes, it does not create a table... is there a debug procedure with v_message and v_operation?

Comment: What is v_message or v_operation? I don't see them in your code. I dare say that the table will be created if the function does not throw an error. Try calling it from the command line with `SELECT f_sync_from_xml();`.